# How Can I Keep A C# Listview Control with Check Boxes from "Checking" on Row Selection?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, .net-1.1, pocketpc

## Environment

- Windows XP x32 Visual Studio 2005 Standard Edition
- Honeywell Dolphin 9500 running Windows Mobile 2003 (Pocket PC 2003) With built in Barcode scanner and B&W camera Using their SDK located [here](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=&cat=&pid=Dolphin9500_&rank=&=#tabs-5).
- .NET Compact Framework 1.0 SP3 and .NET Framework 1.1
- Using VC#

## Goal

I have a ListView control with `CheckBoxes = true` and `View = Details` on a form but I don't want the check boxes to be "checkable" by the user.  I am using it for a status display of record completion.  I do, however, want to use the event handler function to check the box via code (i.e. on record completion: `lvMeters_ItemCheck(null, null);`).

## Problem

I have disabled checking the box itself (I think, the touch screen isn't real precise on this device). However, when selecting a row (I have `FullRowSelect = true`), the control often checks the checkbox and the event handler doesn't seem to be getting called.

## Things I have Tried

I tried to basically undo the action in the event handler:

```
private void lvMeters_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListView)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
            lvMeters.Items[e.Index].Checked = true;
        else
            lvMeters.Items[e.Index].Checked = false;
    }
    else if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
        lvMeters.Items[e.Index].Checked = false;
    else
        lvMeters.Items[e.Index].Checked = true;
}
```

The problem is the above handler doesn't get called on a listview select, nor does the SelectedItemChanged event handler call this event handler but it's still checking the box on select.  It does get called when checking the box itself.

## Need additional information?

Ask away and I'll do my best!

## I'm A Novice

So please feel free to tell me I am doing this completely wrong and should do the entire thing differently.

Comment: +1 for a really well formatted/thought out question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh...I somehow managed to remove the event handler from the control when muddling with the designer.  I checked at some point and it was still there but at that point I actually did have a logic/code problem.

Thanks for your answers :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the limits of the ListView on the compact framework, but on the standard framework, you can use the [TreeNode.StateImageIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.stateimageindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property. The unchecked/checked states are in fact using small images embedded in the standard winforms code (If I remember correctly, they are index 1 and 2). So, for example, if you do this:

```
private void lvMeters_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.StateImageIndex = 3;
}
```

It will change the small icon and set it to nothing. You can also use the ListView ImageList.

Comment: The problem is that my lvMeters_ItemCheck event handler function isn't getting called unless I explicitly click on the Check Box portion of each item in the ListView.  If I click on a portion of the item in another column, it doesn't call the handler but will often check the box.